# How to check if a function is minimum to functional?

Tags: calculus-of-variations

Given $\int_0^1(y')^3dx$ functional and $y(0) = 0 ,y(1)=1$ conditions. Using Euler–Lagrange equation I have got $y(x)=x$. So $y$ is a stationary point of the functional. How to check if it is the minimum for $y \in C^2[0,1]$ ?

Comment: Compute a second variation, see if its positive definite at $y(x) = x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the function 
$$
y(t) = \begin{cases} -\lambda t & \text{ for $t <1/\lambda$} \\\\
        \frac{2}{\lambda-1} (\lambda t-1) -1  & \text{for $t\ge 1/\lambda$}.
   \end{cases}
$$
You have 
$$
\int_0^1 (y')^3\, dx = -\lambda^2 + (1-1/\lambda)\left(\frac{2\lambda}{\lambda-1}\right)^3 \to -\infty \qquad \lambda\to +\infty
$$
hence your functional does not have an absolute minimum.

It is possible to smooth out the function $y(t)$ to get a $C^\infty$ function with the same property.

Comment: Thanks, what about $y \in C^2[0,1]$. I think $y=x$ is minimum there

Comment: No, you can find a counterexample with a $C^2$ function (just smooth out the angle point)

Comment: Is there a option to check whether a stationary point is extermum ?

Comment: If your functional is strictly convex you know that the stationary point is a minimum. If the second variation is positive you know that the point is a local minimum.

Comment: Isn't the second derivative positive for the above example?. Please see this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/334546/how-to-check-if-stationary-point-is-extremum

Comment: What I show is that you don't have an absolute minimum, but you might have a local minimum.