# How to check if stationary point is extremum?

Tags: calculus-of-variations

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332819/how-to-check-if-a-function-is-minimum-to-functional) question the solution of  Euler–Lagrange equation is $y=x$ function.

$L = (y')^3$ so $L''_{y'} = 6y'$ and is positive when $y=x$. But from the answer of Emanuele Paolini follows that it is not enough to $y$ be a minimum.

So what is the general method of checking whether a stationary point is extremum?

Answer (score 1):

If everything with your example is ok, then the function y(x) = x will be a *local* minimizer. If your functional is not convex (as in your case) it is very hard to verify that you have found a *global* minimizer.

Maybe the best chance is the so-called zero-th order sufficient condition: The objective $J$ satisfies $J(f) \ge j$ for some $j \in \mathbb{R}$ and all feasible $f$ and $J(\bar f) = j$ for some feasible $\bar f$.